# How to route to a nested resource whilst not routing to the outer parent resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the following code:

```
resources :subjects do
  resources :partipicants
end
```

I want to route /subjects/x/partipicants etc

But I do not want to route /subjects etc. (i.e. the regular outer resource).

Anyone know how to pull this off cleanly?

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
resources :subjects, :only => [] do
  resources :partipicants
end
```